# Construction injection and JPA repositories

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

With respect to [Why field injection is evil](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) I would like to use in my Spring application construction inject instead of field injection.

My question - how to inject JPA repository - where to get instance (into my `@Service` bean) that is not instantiated as a bean?

Answer (score 0):

You could use constructor injection.
It has not the drawbacks of fields injection by reflection.
Here is an example from [Spring](https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3)

```
@Service
public class FooService {

    private final FooRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public FooService(FooRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I need to know from where to get instance of JPA repository, I need one when I am creating instance of another bean. '@Bean FooService fooService(){ return new FooService({jpa repository instance}); }'

Comment: In that case you add a method parameter to fooService: `@Bean FooService fooService(FooRepository repository) {}`. Spring will automatically inject the repository there.